# PHP mail not working with Exchange 2013

Tags: php, html, email

I  used this code previously and it worked with Microsoft exchange 2010. Now that my corporation uses Microsoft exchange 2013, it does not work.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
<?php

ini_set ("SMTP","mail.***.com");
ini_set("sendmail_from","motabaat@***.com");
$to         = $row_assignto['Email'];      //$row_senmailto['Email'];
$subject    = $row_DetailRS1['TaskName'];
$mail_body  ='<html>
  <p align="right"><strong>
  الاخوة والاخوات     مع حفظ الألقاب
  </strong></p>
  <p align="center"><strong>  الموضوع : ' .$subject. ' </strong></p>
  <p align="right"><strong> ,,,تحية طيبة وبعد  </strong></p>        
  <p align="right"><strong>  يهديكم مكتب معالي الأمين  العام  أسمى التحيات، وبرجاء متابعة     الموضوع أعلاه </strong></p>
  </strong></p>
  <p align="right"><strong>.
  لمعاينة المتابعة <a href="my link"> إضغط هنا </a> </strong></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p align="center"><strong>وتفضلوا بقبول فائق الإحترام     والتقدير،،،،</strong></p>
  <p align="left"><strong>  مكتب معالي الأمين  العام   
  </body>  
  </html>';


$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n" .
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "motabaat@pmo.gov.ps" . "\r\n" . 
"CC:".$row_DetailRS1['AssignCc'];


mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $headers); 

echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=indexadmintask.php\">"; 

?>
```

Comment: Did you do any basic debuggin? Check the return value from `mail()` for boolean false (aka failure)? Check the exchange logs to see what happened to the email, assuming PHP managed to hand it over successfully?

Comment: What exactly about it doesn't work? Where is the PHP mail being sent from? Is it on the same network as the exchange server? Have you tried using a mailer library like PHPMailer or Swiftmailer?

Comment: yap in the same network my exchange ip address is 10.10.0.4 and my code server in 10.10.0.15

Comment: A couple notes: 1. You're missing the opening <body> tag. 2. Your headers are being created strangely. For example the MIME is lost entirely since since $headers gets rewritten in the line below. 3. Can you verify that your arrays have what you want them to? 4. Anything in the error logs? Any error output to the screen? Little things really but they'll help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be your whole problem, but I'm sure this doesn't help:

```
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers = "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n" .
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "motabaat@pmo.gov.ps" . "\r\n" . 
"CC:".$row_DetailRS1['AssignCc'];
```

should be rewritten as:

```
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit" . "\r\n\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: motabaat@pmo.gov.ps" . "\r\n"; // guess
$headers .= "Cc: " . $row_DetailRS1['AssignCc'];
```

That's assuming the actual content of the headers is correct...